# What to do with nginx cache for HTML files?

Tags: html, caching, nginx

I keep running into issues with caching for `HTML` files in my projects.

I have a cache bust mechanism for static resources (images, scripts, css etc..) but all these solutions seem to not handle `HTML` cache problem.

I added `expires 0;` to `Nginx` on all `HTML` files, but it seems to me I am missing an obvious solution.

```
location ~ / {
    if ( $document_uri ~* \.(html)$ ){
         expires 0;
    }
    root /var/www/my-website;

}
```

that looks so ugly(!) and besides, [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and I am certain all websites in the world need to handle this issue, so there's got to be a better way to resolve this.

In angular I tried using `html2js` - which basically turns all the `HTML` files to JavaScript and then it undergoes the same cache bust mechanism as the rest.

But that also forces users to download a big fat JavaScript file, which defeats in some way the use in angular - which loads the templates as needed, making it very light and fast.

How can I resolve `HTML` cache problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 2 almost equal variants, place them after location ~ / {} section:

```
location ~ \.html$ {
  add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
...
}
```

or

```
location ~ \.html$ {
  expires -1;
...
}
```