# How to use HTTP caching in nginx for html files?

Tags: html, caching, nginx, web-hosting, http-caching

My current nginx configuration for HTTP content caching is something like this:

```
location ~* \.html$ {
    expires -1;
}

location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 168h;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

As you see I've disabled caching on the HTML files since they get updated quite frequently.
Now I want to update my configuration with HTML caching enabled by using a script to rename the parent directory of my html files. From:

> view/*.htmls

To

> view/randomString/*.htmls

So, basically what's happening is all my html files will be moved to a directory with random name, that will be generated during each deployment of the web-app. Is it the right approach? Or there is already a better way to achieve this?

Comment: `HTML files since they get updated quite frequently` this is not related to the question, but if you update your HTML often, you probably should use a content management system (CMS) instead.

Comment: @lie frequent updates to textfiles is not a reason to use a cms.  Source code is a set of frequently updated textfiles, yet I don't see anyone use a cms as a development tool.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661538/what-to-do-with-nginx-cache-for-html-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a good grasp on how HTTP caching works. It's a good idea to read that section of the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13).

Instead of changing all the urls with every single release and breaking all bookmarks people may have made, you could give Entity Tag Cache Validators (or [ETags](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13#sec13.3.2)) a try. You can have [nginx create etags](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag) for your html files. Al you have to do to have nginx regenerate them is change the timestamp by [touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix))ing all files you changed.

PS if you run a really really busy thing, and want to avoid the requests that ETags do for checking them. You can set a long expire date like you have for your other files and change the urls by appending `?randomstring` to urls, like is explained in [Cache busting via params](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9692665/383793)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using angular http interceptor for appending the randomString. So, it was not going to change the url.
But your solution seems more logical. Thanks.