# Html files cached regardless of nginx configuration

Tags: caching, nginx

I took the most basic nginx.conf example and tried to add a no-cache control on html files. Tried everything I found, nothing seems to work. This is my config file at the moment

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  3;

pid logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen      [::]:80;

        location / {
            location ~\/.+ {
                root /var/www;
                index index.html index.htm;
            }

            location ~* \.html$ {
               expires -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is what am I doing wrong is it because of nginx or because of something else?

Comment: How do you know your HTML files are being cached?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661538/what-to-do-with-nginx-cache-for-html-files

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration has multiple problems. You have defined a `location ~* \.html$` block with no defined `root`. You also unnecessarily nest the location blocks.

Try something like this:

```
root /var/www;
index index.html index.htm;

location / {
}

location ~* \.html$ {
    expires -1;
}
```

The `root` and `index` directives are defined at the `server` block level to be inherited by all location blocks.

See [the `root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [the `location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more details. Also, this overview of [how `nginx` processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).